# How to create directories using the C standard library (or otherwise)?

Tags: c, file-io

Help appreciated. Couldn't find any mention of this in "the book" (k&r).

Comment: It's not in "the book" (or rather The Standard) because the concept of 'directory' does not apply to all computer architectures out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling the `mkdir()` function. That links to the manual page online. To get that page on your (Linux) machine, enter in a terminal:

```
$ man 2 mkdir
```

The '2' is important, and is called the [manual page section number](http://www.december.com/unix/ref/mansec.html). Since you want help for the C function "mkdir", as opposed to the command-line command "mkdir", you need to specify the section as otherwise you will get the command by default.

Comment: Does this work on windows? If it's C standard library, should work in windows as well right?

Answer (score 3):

Although not part of the standard library, most implementations do include mkdir():

```
#include <dir.h>
...
mkdir("directory");
```

Comment: Which system uses that header and that call?  POSIX requires a different header (`<sys/stat.h>`) and a call with two arguments.

Comment: You are correct, it might be C++ specific. I found the reference here: http://poli.cs.vsb.cz/c/help/dir0.htm

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can use the POSIX [`mkdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir).

For documentation, click that link or try `man 2 mkdir` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
NAME
   mkdir - create a directory

SYNOPSIS
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>

   int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
CONFORMING TO
   SVr4, BSD, POSIX.1-2001.
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it's 2023 now, and there is still no way to create a directory with pure standard library of C language, because there are still OSes without directories, and there is still no convention about all this computing stuff about what we want to be the standard.

for MS Windows use:

```
#ifdef _WIN32               /*  or whatever name for MS target platform,  */
                            /*  according to your compiler convention..   */
    #include <direct.h>  

#endif

/* ... */ 

directory_name[] = "my_folder";

_mkdir(directory_name);

/* ... */
```

for UNIX use:

```
#ifdef __unix__        

    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/stat.h> 

#endif

/* ... */ 

directory_name[] = "my_folder";

mkdir(directory_name, 0777);   /*  second argument is access-rights  */

/* ... */
```

[gcc constant names for most platforms](https://iq.opengenus.org/detect-operating-system-in-c/)

For clang i did not find constant names, only know that for MS Windows `WIN32` works ok with clang compiler; only found [clang supported platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036909/how-to-list-supported-target-architectures-in-clang)

p.s don't forget about platform-dependent slash-styles for directory paths — `\` is MS-style, `/` is UNIX-style.

Answer (score -4):

[mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)