# CLANG - what platforms are supported for cross-compilation?

Tags: clang

Sorry for the broad question; spending several minutes on their [homepage](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html), the only information that I could find was how awesome the compiler is.

What platforms does CLANG support (I am mainly interested in embedded)? ARM, AVR, RTOS etc.
Are there other popular front-ends to LLVM, that are relevant to the question?

Comment: All supported CPUs are listed in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576360/377393

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang: how to list supported target architectures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036909/clang-how-to-list-supported-target-architectures)

Comment: @abyss.7, I agree, voted to close. Thanks for linking to a question with a good answer!

Comment: You can simply delete the question, while there is no answers.