# LLVMCreateDisasm returns NULL

Tags: c, llvm, disassembly

I am trying to disassemble some bytes using LLVM's C interface .
 However `LLVMCreateDisasm()` returns NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS

#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS // llvm complains otherwise
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#include <llvm-c/Disassembler.h>

int main()
{
    LLVMDisasmContextRef dc = LLVMCreateDisasm (
        "testname",
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    if (dc == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create disassembler");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am on x64 Linux.
Looking at the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCDisassembler.html#ga4ab4dad1fdcb9e651fa60f6059ab09b4) seems like I am doing everything right.

```
LLVMDisasmContextRef LLVMCreateDisasm   (
    const char *             TripleName,
    void *                   DisInfo,
    int                      TagType,
    LLVMOpInfoCallback       GetOpInfo,
    LLVMSymbolLookupCallback SymbolLookUp 
)
```

> Create a disassembler for the TripleName. Symbolic disassembly is supported by passing a block of information in the DisInfo parameter and specifying the TagType and callback functions as described above. These can all be passed as NULL. If successful, this returns a disassembler context. If not, it returns NULL.

## Update

1. My llvm version is 3.4
2. I tried every possible triple/target I could think of, still the same.
3. Inserted `printf`'s in [lib/MC/MCDisassembler/Disassembler.cpp: LLVMCreateDisasmCPU()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MC_2MCDisassembler_2Disassembler_8cpp_source.html) and it fails upon first `if` check. The `Error` string at that point is `"Unable to find target for this triple (no targets are registered)"`

   ```
   LLVMDisasmContextRef LLVMCreateDisasmCPU(const char *Triple, const char *CPU,
                                        void *DisInfo, int TagType,
                                        LLVMOpInfoCallback GetOpInfo,
                                        LLVMSymbolLookupCallback SymbolLookUp){
       std::cout << ">>> Triplename: " << Triple << std::endl;
       // Get the target.
       std::string Error;
       const Target *TheTarget = TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(Triple, Error);
       if (!TheTarget) {
           std::cout << "Failed 1: " << Error << std::endl;
           return 0;
       }
       ...
   ```

   So it fails at `lookupTarget` call.
4. Looking at [lib/Support/TargetRegistry.cpp: lookupTarget()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/TargetRegistry_8cpp_source.html) it fails upon first `if` check. The comment there gives some clues:

   ```
   const Target *TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(const std::string &TT,
                                              std::string &Error) {
       // Provide special warning when no targets are initialized.
       if (begin() == end()) {
           Error = "Unable to find target for this triple (no targets are registered)";
           return 0;
       }
       ...
   ```

   So it turns out I have to initialize a target first.
5. In my code I first call `LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();` from the `llvm-c/Target.h` header. Now it fails on second `if` check in [Disassembler.cpp: LLVMCreateDisasmCPU()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MC_2MCDisassembler_2Disassembler_8cpp_source.html)

   ```
   const MCRegisterInfo *MRI = TheTarget->createMCRegInfo(Triple);
   if (!MRI) {
       std::cout << "Failed 2: " << Error << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   with this `Error` string: `Could not create disassembler`

## Finally Solved!

I just had to call `LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();`, `LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();`, `LLVMInitializeAllDisassemblers();` before creating disasm context:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS

#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS // llvm complains otherwise
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#include <llvm-c/Disassembler.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>

int main()
{
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();
    LLVMInitializeAllDisassemblers();

    LLVMDisasmContextRef dc = LLVMCreateDisasm (
        "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    if (dc == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create disassembler");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: So, `testname` is a valid architecture ("host triplet")? Isn't that supposed to be something like `i386-apple-darwin` or `arm-linux-gnu`, etc.?

Comment: @H2CO3 Hmm, docs didn't explain what Triple Name is, so I assumed it's just debugger's name. Anyway, I tried `x86_64-linux-gnu`, `i386-apple-darwin`, `arm-linux-gnu` - same result.

Comment: a "triple" in the context of compilers is generally the 3-part description of the target architecture. What is your system? Does one of the combinations you tried actually match it? (BTW, I don't know if this is something LLVM does/supports, but did you compile LLVM with disassembling enabled? Does this even make sense? [I don't remember the last time I've tried to build LLVM.])

Comment: I'm on x64 Linux. `gcc -dupmachine` says `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

Comment: You can try that as well then.

Comment: Just tried - same result.

Comment: Hm, strange. Let me think about this more.

Comment: @user2529583, what is your version of LLVM? To debug the error you can debug llvm sources here: [MC/MCDisassembler/Disassembler.cpp](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MC_2MCDisassembler_2Disassembler_8cpp_source.html) -  `LLVMCreateDisasmCPU` with debug build and gdb or even with printf's.

Comment: @osgx I inserted printf's in `Disassembler.cpp` in `LLVMCreateDisasmCPU` function at first `if` check. The `Error` string at that point is: `Unable to find target for this triple (no targets are registered)`.

Comment: @user2529583, Thanks, and what is the triple you are using now? There are many initializers in the LLVM, not only the `LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos`, but also `LLVMInitializeAllTargets`,  `LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs`, `LLVMInitializeAllDisassemblers`,  etc https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/include/llvm-c/Target.h?logsort=rev&diff_format=h&r1=192697&r2=192696&pathrev=192697 or even `LLVMInitializeNativeTarget` is you are working in native (via [Target.h](http://root.cern.ch/svn/root/vendors/llvm/include/llvm-c/Target.h))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of `LLVMCreateDisasm`, the

```
"testname"
```

is not valid [TripleName](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Triple.html). TripleName will instruct the LLVM what is the your target, and this is needed because LLVM contains support for several targets in the single installation.

You can list supported targets architectures by running command

```
llc  -version
```

And there are targets for x86 and x86_64

```
x86      - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
x86-64   - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
```

To construct the correct TripleName you should find for your target some good subarch (i486 or x86_64), then add vendor and OS:

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Triple_8h_source.html

```
00022 /// Triple - Helper class for working with autoconf configuration names. For
00023 /// historical reasons, we also call these 'triples' (they used to contain
00024 /// exactly three fields).
00025 ///
00026 /// Configuration names are strings in the canonical form:
00027 ///   ARCHITECTURE-VENDOR-OPERATING_SYSTEM
00028 /// or
00029 ///   ARCHITECTURE-VENDOR-OPERATING_SYSTEM-ENVIRONMENT
```

There is ArchType enum here with list of recognized Arch's in the comment (actual parser is [lib/Support/Triple.cpp - parseArch](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Triple.cpp#221)), like

```
arm,     // ARM: arm, armv.*, xscale
aarch64, // AArch64: aarch64
....
x86,     // X86: i[3-9]86
x86_64,  // X86-64: amd64, x86_64
```

In the same file there are valid vendors (`enum VendorType`), OS types (`enum OSType`) and Envronments (`enum EnvironmentType`). In most cases you can use "unknown" for vendor and os, but often "-unknown-linux-gnu" is used.

Some examples of valid `TripleName`s:

```
x86_64--linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
i486--linux-gnu
```

There are more description of valid triples of clang here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html and some valid names listed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576360/196561

Another limitation in  `LLVMCreateDisasm` is that not all Targets has the `MCDisassembler`s implemented. For example, in LLVM-2.9 [there are](http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=RegisterMCDisassembler&project=adobe) MCDissasemblers only for X86, X86_64, ARM and MBlaze; in more recent (svn from 2014-02-01) [also for](http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=RegisterMCDisassembler&project=llvm) Sparc, PPC, MIPS, SystemZ, XCore and AArch64.

If you was unable to create MCDisassembler even with correct triple, there are several options to debug the `LLVMCreateDisasmCPU` function from MC/MCDisassembler/Disassembler.cpp file. You can break into in with gdb, and then do "next"-stepping until error (this will be more beautiful and easier with debug build of LLVM); or you can add some debugging printf's into the `LLVMCreateDisasmCPU` or temporary change return value from plain NULL info some different for each of error.

UPDATE: Seems that your LLVM was not initialized at time of call. There are many LLVM Initializers in the [llvm-c/Target.h](http://root.cern.ch/svn/root/vendors/llvm/include/llvm-c/Target.h) header in current LLVM (~3.4 or newer):

> `LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos()` - The main program should call this function if
>       it wants access to all available targets that LLVM is configured to
>       support.
>
> `LLVMInitializeAllTargets()` - The main program should call this function if it
>       wants to link in all available targets that LLVM is configured to
>       support.
>
> `LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs()` - The main program should call this function if
>       it wants access to all available target MC that LLVM is configured to
>       support.
>
> `LLVMInitializeAllDisassemblers()` - The main program should call this function
>       if it wants all disassemblers that LLVM is configured to support, to make
>       them available via the TargetRegistry.
>
> `LLVMInitializeAllAsmPrinters()` - The main program should call this function if
>       it wants all asm printers that LLVM is configured to support, to make them
>       available via the TargetRegistry.

and so on (https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/include/llvm-c/Target.h?logsort=rev&diff_format=h&r1=192697&r2=192696&pathrev=192697).

There is even `LLVMInitializeNativeTarget` function which initializes native target:

> `LLVMInitializeNativeTarget()` - The main program should call this function to
>       initialize the native target corresponding to the host.  This is useful 
>       for JIT applications to ensure that the target gets linked in correctly.

Comment: If one can stand to use C++, `llvm::sys::getProcessTriple()` (which requires the `llvm/Support/Host.h` header) gives the correct triple for the executing process. It's intended explicitly to support the JIT use-case.