# clang compiler options aren't documented?

Tags: c++, xcode, migration, clang, compiler-options

For the sake of migrating compiler options to ARM using Xcode, I'm looking for a comprehensive documentation for clang c++ compiler/linker options. The closest I could get was [this page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html), however:

1. Many options aren't explained, e.g. `-arch`, `-arch_errors_fatal`, `-sub_umbrella` and many more.
2. There are options in the Xcode command line that are missing in this doc, e.g. `-Wno-four-char-constants`, `-Wshorten-64-to-32` etc.

Is there any place where I could find a full documentation with generous explanations for each option? Please note, I don't need the meaning of the options I gave here as examples, only for a comprehensive reference.

Comment: `man clang` lays it out pretty well.

Comment: For `-W` options see here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html (note that the prefix `no-` is used to disable a diagnostic. So drop it when searching for documentation).

Comment: @sweenish `man clang` omits many options, e.g. `-target`. 
@rustyx Good to know!

Comment: Some information may be read from `llc -help`, (installed together with llvm). Particular `-target` options will be printed with `llc -version` command. (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036909/clang-how-to-list-supported-target-architectures)

Comment: I don't have an `llc` installed (MacOS High Sierra, Xcode 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in general, you need to refer to [Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html) and to the [Cross-compilation using Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#cross-compilation-using-clang).

Update:

- If you cannot find the argument you need, please go to the bottom of the page to [Search Page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/search.html).
- Paste the argument and press "Search".
- If the argument is supported, you will see its description.

For example, if you look for `-arch_errors_fatal` it will show [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html?highlight=arch_errors_fatal#cmdoption-clang1-arch-errors-fatal):

> Static analyzer report output format (html|plist|plist-multi-file|plist-html|sarif|text).
>
> -ansi, --ansi
> -arch 
> -arch_errors_fatal

It is not very descriptive but on the top of the same page, you can see:

> Introduction
> This page lists the command line arguments currently supported by the GCC-compatible clang and clang++ drivers.

Hence, this specific flag was added for compatibility with the GCC, so you need to look for it in the GCC's documentation.

So you do the following:

- `man gcc`.
- Press `/`, paste `-arch_errors_fatal`, and press Enter. This is the search in the man page.
- press `n` until you find the relevant information.
  For this specific flag it will show you:

> -arch_errors_fatal
> Cause the errors having to do with files that have the wrong architecture to be fatal.

I forgot that MacOS comes without GCC nowadays, so you can lookup the GCC manual page [online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

Looking for information about open-source tools might be not very straight-forward but yet feasible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I use those references when both -arch_errors_fatal and -sub_umbrella aren't explained (and many other options)?

Comment: almost there! what about -sub_umbrella? What does it do?

Comment: It becomes funny:)
Lookup this flag on the GCC man page, it clearly says that "These options are passed to the Darwin linker.  The Darwin linker man page describes them in detail.". Run `man ld` and lookup there: "The specified framework will be re-exported.  Only used when creating a dynamic library."