# Using LLVM-based tools (clang, Rust, Zig) to compile for N64

Tags: rust, clang, llvm, mips, zig

I’m trying to use the LLVM-based `zig cc` to compile C code (and eventually other LLVM-based languages like Rust/Zig) for the R4300i / VR4300 MIPS CPU, which is the processor in the N64. But I don't see any evidence or examples of compiling for VR4300 as a target:

- [the compilation guides](https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64/blob/66018e9f3caaa67399218971d61366cb3f7ba7d7/Makefile#L22) / [tools](https://github.com/matt-kempster/m2c) I’ve seen instruct using GCC / IDO for compilation, making no mention of LLVM-based C compilers (not even the more mainstream ones like clang).
- I don't see it listed in `zig targets`.
- I don't see any way to list the valid targets available for LLVM.

Does LLVM not support the VR4300 as a compilation target? How would I find this out on my own?

Comment: I'd guess that GCC *was* used because it was one of the first with support, but clang and LLVM are not to be underestimated and have been catching up fast in areas where they were behind.

Comment: @tadman possibly. but the VR4300 is quite old at this point, and I imagine it isn't used heavily in industry. so if LLVM never supported it historically, I don't think there would be any pressure these days to add support at this point. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ still hoping!

Comment: You'll have to search around and see what's up. Someone may well have done it as a "fun" hobby project.

Comment: @tadman I did "search around", but I didn't find anything conclusive (nothing said "it is supported", nothing said "it is NOT supported"). Hence why I'm asking here; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fair, but it's off-topic here.

Comment: @tadman How is this off-topic? please explain.

Comment: `zig targets` shows mips3 support, and the VR4300 was MIPS III

Comment: For listing valid LLVM targets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036909/how-to-list-supported-target-architectures-in-clang)

Comment: I have removed the off-topic request here. Please note that requesting recommendations for tools, libraries, tutorials, or other off-site resources is not allowed on Stack Overflow. Likewise, asking multiple questions in a single post is not allowed.